# Laravel upgrade to 7.x throwing composer error in ignition package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, upgrade, ignition

Currently I was trying to upgrade a laravel app from 6.x to 7.x, but after installing the required package 'facade/ignition' I got the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In QueryRecorder.php line 22:

  Argument 2 passed to Facade\Ignition\QueryRecorder\QueryRecorder::__construct() must be of the type bool, null given
  , called in /var/www/html/vendor/facade/ignition/src/IgnitionServiceProvider.php on line 386


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

The package version was `^2.5`, now that I found the solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that I didn't clear the cache. So I recommend you guys before updating anything clear your cache, views, config cache, etc. After clearing the cache the update succeeded.

If you can't run the artisan command to clear the cache, just remove all the files under the `bootstrap/cache/` directory (everything but .gitignore)